# Where to put datatype declarations in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have some data models to declare for my project - just interfaces. The implementation isn't necessarily in a class -- some of it's just read from a JSON file for instance.
Where's the best place to put those declarations? In a `models.ts` file which I import as `import { Model1 } from '@/models'` or in a `models.d.ts` (which is somehow auto-imported by everything -- seems dangerous!)?

For instance:

```
export interface InterviewQuestion {
    name: string
    question: string
    type: string
    expanded?: string
    options?: string[]
    // and maybe others:
    [key: string]: string | number | string[] | undefined
}
```

(I admit I'm thinking about this as a long-time C++ programmer -- I think of these models as my "header file". I realize that may be wrong in a typescript world.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In a models.ts file which I import as import { Model1 } from '@/models'"

Looks good to me

The "d.ts" file is used to provide typescript type information about an API that was written in JavaScript.